# Laravel 5.8 - Error en configuración inicial

Tags: laravel, artisan

Estoy desarrolando un sistema en laravel desde cero y he realizado la instalación en base a los manuales y este momento mediante artisan he realizado:

php artisan make:aut

se ha creado todo, pero al dar click ya se en la opción de Login o Register se muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]